# Add new field to paradox database file

Tags: python, paradox

I am reading a .db paradox database file by `pypxlib` package. And using insert function I can add a new row. But how can I add new fields?

```
from pypxlib import Table
data = Table('test.db')
data.fields
>>OrderedDict([('Index', <pypxlib.DoubleField at 0x18a54cc5d68>),
         ('X', <pypxlib.DoubleField at 0x18a54cc5c88>),
         ('Y', <pypxlib.DoubleField at 0x18a54cc5cf8>)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The database has a fixed schema. To add new fields you need to create a new table, or need to execute an SQL Alter statement (if supported). But since this is legacy technology I would not recommend this last option.